# Can I submit an iOS app with multiple targets to the Appstore?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've developed an iOS app with multiple targets in the same Xcode project. The app is for multiple clients that share the same code but only have changes in layout design (logo, colours, etc...)

**My question is:** How do I submit the app to the *Appstore* for each client? Do I create a new app in *iTunes Connect* with the bundle id that I want to target on the binary?

Is it ok with Apple guidelines?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do create a new app for each client, each app should have a unique bundle ID.

But be aware if Apple find that you a uploading the same app under different names to many time they might reject your app.

> **[4.3 Spam](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#spam)**
>
> Don’t create multiple Bundle IDs of the same app. If your app has different versions for specific locations, sports teams,
>   universities, etc., consider submitting a single app and provide the
>   variations using in-app purchase. Also avoid piling on to a category
>   that is already saturated; the App Store has enough fart, burp,
>   flashlight, and Kama Sutra apps already. Spamming the store may lead
>   to your removal from the Developer Program.

Comment: The best way is to distribute .ipa files privately to your clients. You can use betafamily for it.

Comment: @WasimSafdar Yes and No, yes this is great for beta testing but not for distribution since you can only have up to a 100 test devices or 1000 test user. This is very limiting.

Comment: Then you need some kind of registration process, either they loginIn through web service, FB/Firebase. Depending on their ID, you can change design, layout or functionality programmatically. Or distribute .ipa files by mail.

Comment: If you distribute the ipa you are limited to a 100 test device, thus is is not suitable.

Comment: right, but this limit is also enforced by apple test flight. You need some registration process for your customers and then you can do it in coding and then release it on app store.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the bundle Identifier of the project in Info.plist and then you can upload the same app to the Appstore multiple times.

> However, consider not uploading the same application with different identifiers as long as their UI and codes look visually the same.

The visual aesthetics should be different in each application. Consider tweaking the UI, colour, Logo, App Icon and so forth. This should be consider legal henceforth.

Kind Regards,
Suman Adhikari